Japanese Maple - Possible parasite identification?
Location: Pacific Northwest (Portland, OR)
I have a Japanese Maple and just found this at the node between a stem and leaf:

It looks like a cluster of insect eggs, and the spheres almost look like plastic.  On my display monitor (color calibrated), the color in the image is an accurate representation of the actual color.
Any idea what this is, and if it will damage the tree?

A bit of Googling "light blue insect eggs" revealed a consensus that they belong to Marmorated Stinkbugs, which happen to be relatively common around here.
Probably should have tried searching first... sorry for the waste of bandwidth :-(

The stinkers are fairly common here as well, and your photo is quite an excellent example of egg specimens, so the discourse was quite beneficial. Glad you were able to identify the buggers.

Bug identification, especially when still in egg form, is more than likely going to require the knowledge of a regional entomologist. I am sure the Oregon extension service has one who will really know his stuff, although not necessarily warranted in this instance, you might want to get the information about whom to talk with nonetheless.
Discovering egg casings of that size and small quantity on a Japanese maple in your region is something I personally would not be concerned about. Japanese Maples are tough plants, and fairly pest resistant. Your region does have a good freeze or two, which ensures the insects don't get too out of hand. I would just knock them off and crush the eggs with my foot. If you discovered your tree encased in those eggs, then that would be another matter, but that would be something you would be acutely aware of from visually seeing whatever was flying around and laying them.
If it gets worse, or you just want to check the box. You can also mix a light solution of 3tbsp of neem oil to 1 gallon of water, along with a drop of hand soap to act as an ionic surfactant. Make sure you check the mixing instructions before doing though, as I do not know what concentration of neem oil is available in your region, and I am going by what I can remember off the top of my head. Apply the neem with a sprayer set to a fine pattern, making sure to thoroughly cover the leaves, paying special attention to underneath the leaves where critters hide. Avoid application in strong sunlight, heat, and windy conditions.
Best of luck with your tree, when trained well, they are unparalleled in beauty.
